# Django : request.user not set after redirect

Tags: django, authentication

Specifically, after authentication and redirect, request.user is an anonymous user.

login (view function)

```
def login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = LoginForm(request.POST) 

    if form.is_valid():
        #django.contrib.auth.login
        Login(request, form.get_user())
        str = reverse('cm_base.views.index')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(str)
    else:
            # Their password / email combination must have been incorrect
        pass

else:
    form = LoginForm()

return render_to_response('cm_base/login.html', 
                          {"DEBUG": True,
                           'form' : form
                           },
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in the index view, I removed the login_required decorator and tested the request.user object

```
def index(request):
test = request.user.is_authenticated()

return render_to_response('cm_base/index.html', 
                          {"DEBUG": True,
                           "user": request.user,},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Test returns false.

**Fix**

I ended up just calling the index view directly. I am still confused as to why the user object was lost when I called HttpResponseRedirect.

```
def login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm(request.POST) # Not shown in this example

    if form.is_valid():
        Login(request, form.get_user())
        str = reverse('cm_base.views.index')
        return index(request)
    else:
            # Their password / email combination must have been incorrect
        pass

else:
    form = LoginForm()
```

Comment: Add your entire view logic, there's no way to tell what your form and login method look like from the snippet you have posted.

Comment: Does `request.user.is_authenticated()` return TRUE in login view after you authenticate user?

Comment: Could you share with us your form and login view in a pastebin.com snippet? Thank you.

Comment: Does login in django-admin work?

Comment: @Rohan Yes, it does within the scope of the login view function. Once control leaves that scope, request.user reverts to an Anonymous User.

Comment: @autodidacticon I've had this happen too. Working on the fix now.

Comment: @autodidacticon I had the same problem.

Comment: I have met this problem too. In my case, it was a mistake about options SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN  and SERVER_NAME in settings.py. For example, if SERVER_NAME is "a.b.c", then SESSION_COKKIE_DOMAIN must be "b.c". Please take care about your webserver's configuration if you have one, like nginx/apache, There are options about server name  there too.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of things going on here that shouldn't be. First, you don't need to pass `request.user`, its available by default as long as you are using `RequestContext`, which you are.

`Login()` this method, what exactly is it doing? Django provides a [built-in `login` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) that you should be using if you are using the default authentication backend.

You are also not checking if a user is enabled or disabled.

Here is a different version of your code, adapted from the [example in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def login_view(request):
   form = LoginForm(request.POST or {})
   ctx = {'form': form}

   if form.is_valid():

      username = form.cleaned_data['username']
      password = form.cleaned_data['password']

      user = authenticate(username, password)

      if not user:
         ctx['errors'] = 'Invalid Login'
         return render(request, 'login.html', ctx)

      if not user.is_active:
         ctx['errors'] = 'User is locked'
         return render(request, 'login.html', ctx)

      login(request, user)
      return redirect('home')

   else:

      return render(request, 'login.html', ctx)
```

Answer (score 1):

What auth backend are you using? If it is something other than the ModelBackend make sure your get_user method is correct. It sounds as if the auth middleware is sending a different identifier (like the pk instead of a username) than the one you are looking for in your get_user method.

Comment: This answer worked form me. In my get_user method, I was using email while pk was being sent by Django. When I changed the lookup to `pk=user_id` it worked.

Answer (score -1):

This was the fix

```
<link rel="icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/favicon.ico" />
```

This file was missing from the static directory. The resulting 404 was breaking the user session.